# How to change background (not text) color opacity with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to take an existing background color of a div element and only adjust opacity... how would I do that?

---

Found very simple solution to my problem; requires [jquery-color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin but it's by far the best solution in my opinion:

```
$('#div').css('backgroundColor', $.Color({ alpha: value }));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Opacity is tricky because there's still no cross-browser supported mechanism, even though its supposed to be in CSS3.

What you most likely want to do is change the `background-color` style's alpha channel.
See: http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/11/css-background-transparency-without-affecting-child-elements-through-rgba-and-filters/

---

Someone has developed a JQuery plugin that does just what you want:
http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/backOpacity

With this plugin, you can control just the "back opacity" without affecting child elements.

Comment: [A brief introduction to Opacity and RGBA](http://www.css3.info/introduction-opacity-rgba/).

Answer (score 4):

The [*query-color*](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin is a nice solution, **however** I strongly believe you **do not** need to overload your app with unnecessary plugins for such an easy and simple task.

Here is another approach using **strings**:

```
var alpha = "0.8";

var oldBGColor = $('#div').css('backgroundColor');
// rgb(40,40,40)

var newBGColor = oldBGColor.replace('rgb','rgba').replace(')', ','+alpha+')'); 
// rgba(40,40,40,.8)

$('#div').css('backgroundColor', newBGColor);
```

Here is a [*jsFiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/liormb/SxQt8/1/) example of how to use it.

I had a [*similar problem*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678801/adding-alpha-channel-to-background-color-using-jquery?noredirect=1#comment24007349_16678801) and it made the magic for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to go from opacity x.xxx to 1 you can do

```
var element = $("#id")
element.css('backgroundColor', element.css('backgroundColor').replace(/(\d\.?\d*)\s*\)/i, "1") )
```

to do the inverse just change 1 by the value you want.

Note your color need to have the "rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.85098)" format from the start

Answer (score -1):

Upload your background image or color in Photoshop and decrease the opaity there and save it as .jpeg image and then use it as the background in HTML.

Simple as that.... :D

Comment: JPEG isn't ([usually](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639866/jpeg-image-with-alpha-channel-on-website)) used with opacity. Using images is inefficient to start with, but for the specific purpose of having non-binary opacity, I'd say PNG is the way to go.