# Add Alpha Channel to Background Color using jQuery / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, alpha

I have a jQuery function that adds an **Alpha** channel to a **background-color** when an event occur.

Here is my [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/liormb/SxQt8/1/).

**CSS**

```
div { background-color: rgb(100,100,100); }
```

**JavaScript**

```
function addAlphaChannel() {
    var oldBGColor = $('div').css('backgroundColor'); //rgb(100,100,100)
    var newBGColor = oldBGColor.replace('rgb', 'rgba').replace(')', ',.8)'); //rgba(100,100,100,.8)

    $('div').css({ backgroundColor: newBGColor });
}
```

This code works fine, however I wonder if there is a better way of adding/changing alpha channel?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: use the opacity css property? (but this is not only for the bg-color)

Comment: @bwoebi An opacity will effect ALL my element's children

Comment: Yes, I just said this. But no, I don't see any alternative.

Comment: How does your code work- where does the string called  'color' come from?

Comment: @kennebec It was a typo mistake. Thx for your comment. Hope it make sense now.

Comment: try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177964/in-javascript-how-can-i-set-rgba-without-specifying-the-rgb

Comment: @JamesDaly This solution is using strings as well. My solution is simpler but I can't find a nicer and elegant way of doing it. Thx!

Comment: @JamesDaly I guess I can and I also know how to target my element directly but I'm looking for some more robotic solution that can work with any given element.

Comment: I *think* you're confined to string manipulation, because CSS is sent as raw text. The SO answer that @JamesDaly linked to above has a quite elegant regex manipulation that's more robust than your string replace solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the rgba css property using javascript, you'll need to use the replace method, however, you can improve your code like this:

CSS

```
 div { background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 1.0); }
```

JS

```
function addAlphaChannel() {
    var oldBGColor = $('div').css('background-color'), //rgb(100,100,100),
        newBGColor = oldBGColor.replace(/[^,]+(?=\))/, '0.8'); //rgba(100,100,100,.8);

    $('div').css({ backgroundColor: newBGColor });
}
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Yes, it's another way of the same thing - using strings, Even thou I'm not sure as per as your RegEx syntax (try it yourself), in terms of time/code efficiency, specific replacement (like 'rob' => 'rgba') is faster than using a RegEx engine.