# How to detect the colorspace of an image using Qt?

Tags: qt, image-processing, qimage

I want to detect the colorspace (RGB/CMYK) of the input JPG image, using Qt Image API's. I tried exploring QImage and QImageReader. Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: I found QImage(Reader) to be quite limited regarding this. I suggest using libjpeg to get more information about your image.

Comment: This link https://stackoverflow.com/a/50861048/2836621 plus `exiftool -v YourImage.jpg` should be enough to work it out.